# TF-IDF ranking for nodes with taxonomy term keywords

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, search, rating, database

I would need to implement a ranking system that uses the TD-IDF http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Maybe it looks complicated but isn't

Example: "Consider a document containing 100 words wherein the word cow appears 3 times. Following the previously defined formulas, the term frequency (TF) for cow is then (3 / 100) = 0.03. Now, assume we have 10 million documents and cow appears in one thousand of these. Then, the inverse document frequency is calculated as log(10 000 000 / 1 000) = 4. The TF-IDF score is the product of these quantities: 0.03 × 4 = 0.12."

My situation is similar. I have a bunch of documents tagged with keywords, and I have to determine how relevant one term is pro node author.

I found a MYSQL query for this, here: http://snipplr.com/view/51513/

This is the MYSQL Query

```
SELECT id,
       keyword,
       item_id,
       item_type,
       created_by,
       EXTRACT,
       extract_start,
       extract_end,
       SUM(occurrences / (SELECT keyword_count
                          FROM   keyword_counts
                          WHERE  item_id = t.item_id
                                 AND created_by = [creator user id goes here]
                                 AND item_type = t.item_type) * Log(
               (SELECT COUNT(1)
                FROM   search_results) / ( 1 +
               (SELECT COUNT(1)
                FROM   search_results
                WHERE  '.[keyword '
                        OR ' statements go here].') )))
       AS keyword_density_product
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   search_results
        WHERE  ( '.[keyword '
                  OR ' statements go here].' )
               AND created_by = [creator user id goes here]
               AND item_type = [item type, e.g. 'document', goes here]) t
GROUP  BY item_id
ORDER  BY keyword_density_product DESC
LIMIT  [pagination limit goes here] OFFSET [pagination offset goes here];
```

I would like to translate this to Drupal, it would be a great if somebody could help me.
Thenks

Comment: Which Drupal version are you targeting?